# How to find the coordinates of the fourth vertex of a square in a projective perspective

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

If I suppose that I know the coordinate of three points (eg. `A'B'C'`) in a 2D coordinate system of `A'B'C'D'`, my question is how can I find the coordinate of the fourth point `D'` (the same question for `A''B''C''D''`)? Is it even possible? Do I need more information?

For the rectangle ABCD would be easy to get the coordinates of `D` knowing `ABC`, because it is a normal square in a euclidean geometry, using the simple formula: $$A+B-C,\ A+C-B~or \ B+C-A$$

[image]

The projection used in here is a perspective projection like a pinhole model used by cameras. I do know the intrinsic parameters of the camera (focal length, pixels size..etc) and also the size of the square in real world, however, I don't know the distance Z of that square from the camera. That's parameters matrix:

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_u & 0 & u_0 \\ 0 & \alpha_v & v_0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you know anything at all about the projection? Do you have any reference objects in the image?

Comment: Yes I know the perspective projection and how the 3D world is projected into an image and I'm going to apply the inverse of that projection once I get the fourth vertex. Would you please clarify what is this reference for?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Do you know anything about the *specific* projection you’re working with aside from the coordinates of the images of three out of four vertices of a square? With no other information, there’s no way to determine the image of the missing vertex.

Comment: Yes it is a perspective projection using a pinhole model like in cameras and computer vision. In fact, I'm taking an image of a square using a camera.

Comment: You’re still misunderstanding my questions: do you know any part of the projection’s matrix? Are there any other objects in the scene? As things stand, the vanishing points of the parallel sides of the square could be almost anywhere.

Comment: Sorry for that. I do know the focal length and other intrinsic parameters of the camera as it is calibrated but I don't know the distance Z of the object. I do know the size of the square in real world.

Comment: That helps a lot. You should include that information in your question.

Comment: Well I as thinking of a solution using using some basi geometry like  for the red square ABCD but if there is other solutions that's also fine. I just added some information